# Navigation Drawer - error: failed linking file resources

Tags: java, android-studio

This is my main layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FBFBD8">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:id="@+id/nv">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Second layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#816291">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/man" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Third layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">


    <item android:id="@+id/account"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
        android:title="My Account"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
        android:title="Settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mycart"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon3"
        android:title="My Cart"/>
    </menu>
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.exercise1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;




import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout dl ;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle abdt;
    private NavigationView nv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dl = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        abdt = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, 0, 0);
        dl.addDrawerListener(abdt);
        abdt.syncState();getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        nv = findViewById(R.id.nv);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch(id) {

                    case R.id.account:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.settings:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.mycart:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(abdt.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exercise1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

During the compilation, I get the message: error: failed linking file resources.
Additional information: error: resource menu/navigation_menu (aka com.example.exercise1:menu/navigation_menu) not found. 
What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Check if your third layout file is under *res/menu* directory

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem of error messages, but now the message: "application has stopped".

Comment: Please post here the stack error for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that this "third layout file" is called `src/main/res/menu/navigation_menu.xml`

Also, properties `layout_height` and `layout_width` are useless for a menu resource (which might be the reason for the crash)... and `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` should be migrated to `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`.